# Adding price field on Drupal Commerce that affect Order Price

Tags: commerce

**The case is**

When user place an order, shipping price must be manually calculated before the final invoice is sent to user.

**What I do**

I create Price custom field on Order named *shippingfee*.

**Problem is**

How to make shippingfee field affect the Order price?

Another thing that I tried is creating custom line item type. I'm thinking that by creating this custom line item type would update the value.But following [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1286954) tutorial, the custom line item type did not appear when I check on `admin/commerce/config/line-items`.

Code added to custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_line_item_type_info().
 */
function owemji_commerce_line_item_type_info() {
  return array(
    'owemji' => array(
        'name' => t('Shipping Fee'),
        'product' => false,
        'description' => t('Price of shipping.'),
        'base' => 'owemji',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function owemji_enable() {
  commerce_line_item_configure_line_item_fields(array('owemji'));
}
```

I did try clear cache and disable -> enable the owemji module, but it's still not there.

Comment: FYI: There is a module for custom line item types creation: [Commerce Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product)

Comment: approach with order price is wrong. order price should be calculated with line items. see my answer below about 'commerce_shipping' and 'Commerce Flat Rate' module. It creates shipping line item from the box and takes care about all the calculations. The only thing you need to do is configure rules. See the videos in my answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a contrib module developed espacially for shipping - [Commerce Flat Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate)

> This module allows you to define any number of flat rate shipping
>   services via the user interface in conjunction with [Commerce Shipping
>   2.x.](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) When you define a new flat rate service, you specify the base rate for it in the add / edit form. You can further modify the base
>   rate (enabling things like weight or quantity based shipping) using
>   rate calculation rules.
>
> This is functionally equivalent to using product pricing rules to add
>   discounts or fees to base product prices before adding them to the
>   cart.

There are few old but still actual video casts from [rfay](https://www.drupal.org/u/rfay) about Commerce Shipping. Watch it for a basic understanding:

- [Introduction to Commerce Shipping](https://vimeo.com/32526283)
- [Free Shipping Based on Order
  Value or User Role](https://vimeo.com/32692562)
- [Shipping Discount for Item in Cart using
  Calculation Rules](https://vimeo.com/32816741)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [commerce_fees](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees) and if you want update you price according to user data you can do it with some custom coding and this module is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As @milkovsky said [Commerce Flat Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) seems like the way to go.

Or if you want an even simpler solution : just create a Shipping product and manually add it to your order when you know the shipping.